# MS Graph SDK V5, filter sharepoint list item by a number field

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a simple list that has a number field called EmpId. Type of it is number with 0 decimal places.

I have created an Index on this field as well. Then I run a query where I want to filter by the EmpId. Current query is like below

```
        try
        {
            var user = await graphService.CurrentUser();
            var grClient = await graphService.GetGraphServiceClient([ "Sites.ReadWrite.All"]);
            var response = await grClient.Sites[spSettings.Value.SiteId].Lists[spSettings.Value.LeaveListId].Items
                .GetAsync(builder =>
                {
                    builder.Headers.Add("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual");
                    builder.QueryParameters.Filter = $"fields/EmpId eq '{user.EmployeeId}'";
                    builder.QueryParameters.Expand = ["fields($select=EmpId,Status)"];
                });

            var entries = response.Value;

        }
        catch (ODataError odataError)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Exception Details", odataError);
            throw;
        }
```

This doesn't apply the filter. It returns all items. Note that I tried with and without quotes as well.

I also noticed that when I save values to this EmpId field, the numbers get saved with a decimal place (ex:- if I enter 9, it gets saved as 9.0) even though in SharePoint it doesn't show the decimal place. So I tried using 'x.0'/x.0 (with and without quote) in the filter, still it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?